# share my website news to my facebook wall

Tags: asp.net

i want to share my website news in facebook.
how can my visitor share my news in Their Facebook wall ??

Comment: Are you sure that's a question? Most questions end with a question mark and yours does not make much sense.

Comment: guyumuyu is right. Can get anything out of your question.

Comment: more sites make ass fun page for users to add part of article to your face book see this url 
http://www.ahly.com/news/index.php?news_id=1955

Comment: you will see share on facebook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one you linked to simply is a link in the form:

http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=**http://www.yourlinkhere.com**

Where you will automatically put your link into the bolded piece

Some Javascript that will do this is:

```
<a name="fb_share" type="button" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php">Share</a>   
<script src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share" type="text/javascript">
</script>
```